# How to show message in search if cant find any, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this search form and I want to show a message if the user types in something that does not exist in the database a message like "not found" cause what I have now it only shows an empty tables if it doesn't find anything. How do I make this? this is the code for my search form

**buildings.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'offices','role'=>'search']) !!}
    <div class="input-group col-xs-4 col-md-6" >
        <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." required>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

**OfficeController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $search = \Request::get('search');
    $offices = Office::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')->get(); 
    return view('search', compact('offices', 'search')); 
}
```

Comment: What version of php are you running?

Comment: mine is php 7.2.1 @btl

Answer (score 2):

Do this in a view:

```
@if ($offices->isEmpty())
    Not Found
@elseif
    {{-- Show offices --}}
@endif
```

You can also use one of these methods for the check:

```
@if (count($offices) === 0)
@if ($offices->count() === 0)
@if (empty($offices))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flash a message in session and display it conditionally in your view:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $search = \Request::get('search');
    $offices = Office::where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')->get();
    if (!$offices || !$offices->count()) {
        Session::flash('no-results', 'Your search produced no results');
    }
    return view('search',compact('offices','search')); 
}
```

Then in your view file:

```
@if(Session::has('no-results'))
    <span>{{ Session::get('no-results') }}</span>
@else
    // put the table in here. 
@endif
```

Comment: it says method empty does not exist @btl

Comment: `{!! Form::open(['method'=> 'GET','url'=>'offices','role'=>'search']) !!}`    I tried putting the 2nd one above this form and the search form is not showing @btl

Comment: also when I try to put it inside the form it shows nothing no message @btl

Comment: its not showing anything where exactly should i place this `@if(Session::has('no-results'))
    <span>{{ Session::get('no-results') }}</span>
@endif`      before the form or after? @btl

Comment: I mean its not showing any messages just an empty table @btl